# Error Laravel Charts 7

Tags: php7

Estoy instalando laravel Charts (https://charts.erik.cat/), v7.*
y me está dando un problema terminando el composer update, aparece un mensaje indicando que al momento de publicar el paquete, existe un error de sintaxis en el archivo ChartsServiceProvider.php.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Viendo los requisitos del paquete, actualicé al php7.4, Yo trabajo con Laragon, por lo que me guié de su documentación para colocar una version de php y seleccionarla. Pero continua apareciendo el mismo mensaje de la imagen adjunta. y al revisar en consola, sigue indicando que tengo la versión 7.3 de php

Esta es la línea 23 de la cual habla el error (en ChartsServiceProvider.php)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de mi composer.json

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.4",
    "caouecs/laravel-lang": "~3.0",
    "consoletvs/charts": "7.*",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2": "^1.0.0",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "nesbot/carbon": "2.35.0 as 1.39.0",
    "tcg/voyager": "^1.2",
    "chartisan/php": "^1.2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
    "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
    "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.4.8"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [],
        "providers": [
            "ConsoleTVs\\Charts\\ChartsServiceProvider"
        ]
    }
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "ConsoleTVs\\Charts\\": "src/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
},
"repositories": {
    "hooks": {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://larapack.io"
    }
}
```

}

Cualquier ayuda o comentario es bienvenido
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente preguntando en otros foros, conseguí la respuesta.

A parte de descargar PHP 7.4 y colocarlo en la carpeta de laragon, para seleccionarlo, es necesario añadir laragon al path, tal como muestra la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de reiniciar el sistema, ya puedo contar con php 7.4.8 y no tengo problemas con publicar el paquete laravelCharts.

Esto resuelve el error de sintaxis de funciones flecha (versión de PHP inferior a la 7.4).

Otra solucion o complemento:
EN otro pc que sucedió lo exactamente el mismo problema, tuve que reinstalar composer, ya que mantenía la ruta php que establece xampp u otro.

SOLUCIONADO!

Comment: El problema y para que puedas ampliar tu solución, es que tratabas de usar funciones flecha y tenías hasta antes de esto una versión de PHP inferior a la 7.4 y por eso no te reconocía dicha sintaxis

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo solucione algo similar instalando composer de nuevo seleccionando la versión 7.4 ya que laragon no lo cambiaba en consola me seguís indicando 7.2 asta que reinstale componer. La consola ya me mostraba 7.4. creo que hay alguna forma de cambiarlo en composer sin reinstalar pero no investigue. Si alguien la conose.

Comment: gracias @diasblo66 ya encontré la solucion. la postearé mas abajo.